# Issues with Eclipse using version 2.6.6. Cannot resolve index.render

Tags: eclipse, playframework

Usign version 2.6.6., I am trying to open a project in Eclipse and get an error stating that cannot resolve index.render.[1]

I have added the following to

--- plugins.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.2")

--- build.sbt
// Compile the project before generating Eclipse files, so that generated .scala or .class files for views and routes are present
EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile, compile in Test)

EclipseKeys.projectFlavor := EclipseProjectFlavor.Java           // Java project. Don't expect Scala IDE
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.ValueSet(EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedClasses, EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedResources)  // Use .class files instead of generated .scala files for views and routes

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KquG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install scala from eclipseMarketPlace and restart your eclipse IDE

Comment: Give more specific on your solution.